# How status and details are log in extent report?

Tags: extentreports

I have added new heading to extent report called "expected result" and "actual result" but don't know how to log all the details under the heading. Don't know flow of log method of extent report.[Here is screenshot of my extent report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlVTE.png)

I have tried to create new log method in extent report library but that does not worked because I don't know flow of log method of extent report.